# Sort an NSMutableArray within an NSMutableArray by date property

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have a NSMutableArray that has a inner NSMutableArray that I would like to sort (sort the outer items) by a date property within the inner NSMutableArray.

```
The array looks like this
[
  {
     messages : [
     { 
     date
     },
     ..... etc
     ]
  },
..... etc
]
```

The code below is my attempt that throws an exception

```
NSSortDescriptor *sdSortDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"messages.@lastObject.date" ascending:YES];
events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[events sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sdSortDate]]];
```

example

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[<__NSArrayM 0x604000654670> valueForKeyPath:]: this class does not implement the lastObject operation.'
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `messages.date.@lastObject` instead of `messages.@lastObject.date`. Try the code below

```
NSSortDescriptor *sdSortDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"messages.date.@lastObject" ascending:YES];
events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[events sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sdSortDate]]];
```